# Distribute Instances procedurally with Geometry Nodes, but ALSO avoiding only specific other instances

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm creating a grass field. Let's say I use a noise texture + color ramp to distribute points+instance on points for a green grass patch object. I duplicate the node group and invert the color ramp to distribute a brown grass patch object where the green patch isnt.

I want to also distribute clover patches in the same areas as green patch (so same noise+color ramp), but have it AVOID the green grass or alternatively have the green grass avoid the clover.

I know there is a minimum distance field when Distribute Points is set to Poisson Disk, but i don't know how to make it only avoid clover instances, rather than, say, brown grass patch instances, since i want those to blend together more.

Comment: Okay, some questions for clarification: you have green grass somewhere, and you want brown grass where no green grass is as I understand the first part... Why duplicate the node group? Why not use the one color ramp for distributing green and brown? And when you say clover in areas where green grass is and clover blend with brown grass - so basically you want clover all over the place? But the green and clover should not be to close together, but brown and clover can be close together / in the same location? Or how do you mean that avoding green but blending with brown part?

Comment: hey, thanks for replying. To answer your first question, I have been following a tutorial, so having separate node groups was just how the creator set things up. To elaborate on what I want with the clover and diff grasses: Brown and green grass in opposite areas, this part has already been accomplished. I want clover to only distribute in the same -possible- area as green grass, but I want green grass and clover to avoid each other -within- that defined area

Comment: Okay, so I would use _Poisson Disk_ for the point distribution in the green grass area, then put the clover into a collection together with the green grass. This way you can use the distance. However, if this is not dense enough for you, you might have to split the green area again with noise texture to separate grass and clover, as you did before with green and brown grass.

Comment: By the way, I've got a large lawn at my house and if I were you, I wouldn't separate the clover from the green grass. It's growing pretty much everywhere inbetween ;)